# Mail doesnt work after deploying

Tags: laravel, heroku, mailgun

I am building laravel project, I used mailgun to send emails. Locally it worked just fine. After deploying on heroku it does not send any emails.

services.php

```
'mailgun' => [
'domain' => env('sandbox.....'),
'secret' => env('key-.......'),
```

mail.php

```
driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'example@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'shop'),
],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''),
```

Tried looking at `heroku logs` but cannot see anything about mail so I dont really understand it. What could I be missing?

Comment: Does heroku vahe its own **.env** file set up and are all the needed values are present in it?

Comment: please share the error which you getting after calling the mail service.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when deploying my app. I came up with following checkpoints so it works on production with Heroku. My bet for your issue is number 4.

1. Make sure you have set verified domain correctly (mailgun -> domains -> verified domains & dns - all green).
2. Make sure you updated env variables in Heroku to work with verified domain (heroku -> settings -> reveal config vars) should have fields: `MAILGUN_API_KEY`, `MAILGUN_DOMAIN`, `MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD`, `MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN`, `MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER`, `MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT` with proper values.
3. Make sure you have cleared the list of authorized recipients (mailgun -> domains -> authorized reciepients) - so everyone can receive your emails.
4. Make sure you have cleared the list of IP whitelist (mailgun -> account overview -> account settings -> security -> IP whitelist) or included ip of your Heroku app. Note this point is not about IP management for domain but for your mailgun account.

In my case the only ip there was my localhost ip (for dev) and it was blocking Heroku deployed app for sending emails.